# How do I disable udevd in systemd?

Tags: fedora, udev, systemd, lxc

I'm trying to boot a Fedora Rawhide LXC container from a Fedora 16 host, and it's not working - `systemd` just keeps dropping into emergency mode. Because `udevd` doesn't work in LXC containers, I thought I'd try disabling `udevd` inside the guest, but I can't manage to do this.

You'd think that

```
systemctl disable udev.service
```

would do the trick, but it doesn't. I can see that `udevd` is still being spawned by running `pstree` in the host.

Answer (score 3):

The command is `systemctl` to control the services under `systemd`

to disable the service from running next time: `systemctl disable udevd.service`

to stop the service currently running : `systemctl stop udevd.service`

Go through these doc links from the author of `systemd`

http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd.html

http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/on-etc-sysinit.html

They are lengthy, but worth a leisure reading, and yet important, since major Linux distributions are having this crucial time to leap into next leg of improvement/enhancements with `systemd`, leaving behind some (old school of thoughts) SysV style operations.

Comment: Sorry - I made a couple of typos. That's basically what I did, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

systemd terminology is a little confusing in this regard. `systemctl disable` marks a service to not start at boot, but that service can still be started by other means *after* boot. (For example, dbus activation.) To completely remove a service from ever being activated, use `systemctl mask` instead — then it will be "masked out" and not ever start.

Since this question is Fedora 16 and five years ago, I'm not sure that that's the specific problem and can't really test, but I suspect from the other answers and the comments that this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW in an old LXC container running Debian Bookworm and again on Trixie, I had to use "sudo systemctl mask systemd-udevd.service" to get it to stop failing apt dist-upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

The service on Ubuntu is called "systemd-udevd", so you would run `sudo systemctl stop systemd-udevd`.  You may also have to stop a couple of socket services, which may will show up in the output after you stop systemd-udevd.  I'm assuming Fedora is similar, but I don't have a Fedora machine nearby to test on. :)